# How to save image after upload in circle avatar

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]
Image Success upload

[image]
After go another page

How to save the image after uploading in the avatar circle. My problem is that after the image was successfully uploaded, the image was not successfully saved. So how to make that image to be maintained?

Code design circle avatar

```
bool _imageReadyForPreview = false;

    Center(
                                child: Stack(children: [
                                  !_imageReadyForPreview
                                      ? FutureBuilder(
                                          future: getSignedURL(
                                              widget.patientProfile.avatar,
                                              widget.token),
                                          builder: (BuildContext context,
                                              AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                            if (snapshot.data == null) {
                                              return Container(
                                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                                child: Container(
                                                  width: 200,
                                                  height: 200,
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                        14, 113, 176, 1),
                                                    border: Border.all(
                                                      color: Colors.black12,
                                                      width: 1.0,
                                                    ),
                                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                        Radius.circular(200.0)),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            } else {
                                              return Container(
                                                width: 200,
                                                height: 200,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                                    image:
                                                        NetworkImage(snapshot.data),
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                  ),
                                                  color: Color(0xFF0E71B0),
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      const BorderRadius.all(
                                                    Radius.circular(200.0),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            }
                                          },
                                        )
                                      : Container(
                                          width: 200,
                                          height: 200,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: const Color.fromRGBO(
                                                244, 237, 237, 1),
                                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                                Radius.circular(200.0)),
                                            image: DecorationImage(
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                image: MemoryImage(_bytesData!,
                                                    scale: 0.5)),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 190,
                                    height: 190,
                                    child: Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                        child: InkWell(
                                          onTap: () async {
                                            _startFilePicker();
                                          },
                                          child: const CircleAvatar(
                                            radius: 17,
                                            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0E71B0),
                                            child: Icon(
                                              Icons.add,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )),
                                  )
                                ]),
                              ),
```

File picker code

```
_startFilePicker() async {
    FileUploadInputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();
    uploadInput.click();

    uploadInput.onChange.listen((e) {
      // read file content as dataURL
      final files = uploadInput.files;
      if (files!.length == 1) {
        final file = files[0];
        selectedFile = file;
        //choosenFileName = file.name;
        final reader = new FileReader();
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
        });
        reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
          _handleResult(reader.result!);
        });
        reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
      }
    });
  }
```

HandleResult and upload code

```
Future<void> _handleResult(Object result) async {
    setState(() async {
      _selectedFile = [];
      _bytesData = Base64Decoder().convert(result.toString().split(",").last);
      _selectedFile = _bytesData!;
      _imageReadyForPreview = true;
      uploadFile(widget.token);

      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  uploadFile(String token) async {
    print("Upload start...");
    if (_selectedFile.length < 1) {
      showMessageDialogBox(context, 'Please select a photo.');

      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    var fileContentType = selectedFile.type.split('/');
    var uri = Uri.parse(widget.apiEndPoint);
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
    request.fields['MultipartFile'] = 'true';
    request.fields['API'] = 'UploadImage';
    request.fields['Token'] = widget.token;

    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('File', _selectedFile,
        contentType: new MediaType(fileContentType[0], fileContentType[1]),
        filename: selectedFile.name));

    var streamedResponse = await request.send();
    var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        _progressBarActive = false;
      });
      var result = json.decode(response.body.toString());
      if (result['ResponseCode'] == "0") {
        if (result['Data'] != null) {
          print(result['Data']['banner']);
          setState(() {
            avatar = result['Data']['banner'];
          });
        }
      } else if (result['ResponseCode'] != "0") {
        _alertDialog(context, result['ResponseMsg']);
        if (result['ResponseCode'] == "1") {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              '/signin', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing so the image doesn't successfully persist. I have someone who can help me to give insight on how to solve the problem.

Comment: You may have the user data stored somewhere in the app to manage their logged-in state so you can save the uploaded avatar too when you trigger upload you should refresh the user data after the avatar is uploaded and if no image is selected use image from the user data to show in the circular avatar.